# Get the path of "static" folder in django automatically

Tags: python, django

I am developing Django (1.6) app. In my app I have to use the static images to be displayed on the HTML pages (like magnifying glass for search box,logo,etc). After little bit of research I came to know that we have to create a folder (say "static") which holds the static images and then I have mention the path in my settings.py like shown below :

```
`STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
   "C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/business/static/polls",
   "C:/Users/Welcome/Desktop/business/static",
 )`
```

I also added the code shown below in urls.py too after which I could get the images on my HTML pages.

`urlpatterns = patterns(''......... ...........) + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)`

My question now is every time I change the directory (current working directory or if I transfer the project to another pc )  I have to update the path in settings.py.
How to not do that ? how to get path of "static" folder automatically when I run my project. Please do help. What I'm missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally the static files finder of django will expect that your app itself has a `static` sub-directory, and you can store everything there.

```
+ myproj
  - manage.py
  + app
    - __init__.py
    - settings.py
    - urls.py
    + static     <-- notice the static directory.
    + templates
```

This is good of course for development where the Django server is the one serving these static files. In production you'll need to collect everything to the location declared in your `STATIC_ROOT` setting with the `collectstatic` management command.

This way you won't need to change the location each time you copy your project to a new location or a new computer.

Of course, that once you do that you can drop the `STATICFILES_DIRS` definition from your `settings.py`. This setting is used to tell Django that there are other static assets that reside outside of a certain app. If you want to use it anyway then you can define those directories relative to the project itself, i.e.:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
)
```

Your `urls.py` should then use the `staticfiles_urlpatterns` like this:

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

For more information see the Django documentation on static files:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/howto/static-files/

Comment: and what seems to be the problem?

Comment: My project and app directory follows the same structure as you have mentioned. After all the changes to the path I did run `manage.py collectstatic` command(though I think it will run implicitly while running manage.py runserver). I think I have to modify `STATICFILES_DIRS`as you have mentioned by getting current working directory of the project and mention the folder name.

Answer (score -1):

I just figured out the solution for my question. First you need to get the current working directory and then for looking out for the folder in that current working directory(where your project is being installed) assign this to variable say `path_for_images` and then pass it to the `STATICFILES_DIR` as shown below:

```
path_for_images = os.getcwd()+"\static"
STATICFILES_DIRS = ( path_for images,) <-- note ,(comma) after `path_for_images`
```

No need to do any changes for the `urls.py` and images get loaded. This isn't exact pythonic way but it's surely one of the way.

Comment: I would like to know why it got down voted ? :) If there is other way of doing then please let me know.